# 90 degrees phase shift in AC servo motors

Tags: voltage, circuit-analysis, current, resistors, motor

[IEEE Article1](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/6437738) and
[IEEE Article2](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/5060662?reload=true&arnumber=5060662&contentType=Journals%20%26%20Magazines)

In both of these links, its stated that main winding and control winding in an AC servo position motor are 90 degrees displaced from each other. Why is this so? Any explanation is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: 0 or 90? title says 90, your question main text says 0. Also, the article may not be not accessible to everybody. It will be good if you can post the specific sentence and associated context around it directly in the question.

Comment: 90, typo error, is the link accessible now?

Comment: Only to those who have IEEE membership. Post a link that works for all or risk closure.

Comment: Does the [Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AC_motor#Two-phase_servo_motor) "*... so as to produce a rotating magnetic field ...*" answer your question ? If not, please [edit] more details into to your question.